# database from spreadsheet online

Tags: iphone, database, spreadsheet

I'm creating an iPhone app which is going to have an online spreadsheet to download information from, problem is i have no idea how to do this. I'm not sure how many rows there will be, but there will be 6 columns. How do I access information from this spreadsheet?

Links to tutorials would be nice

Comment: start by getting some books/tutorials maybe? :)

Comment: We need more information. What format is the spreadsheet in? What sort of data does it contain?

Comment: 4 strings and 2 floats. it is really just a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to make some sort of API call on the server to output the spreadsheet in `CSV` format, then use a `CSV` parser on the device once you fetch the data. A [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ios%20csv&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&source=hp&q=iphone%20csv%20parser&aq=f&aqi=g1g-v1&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=e76a40ef62488b62&biw=2008&bih=1240) turn up several solutions for a parser.